# Why do we "get to school" but "get home"?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-usage

I've noticed that we "get to" some places, i.e. school, the gym, work, etc but we only "get home". Why do we omit the "to" for that particular usage?

Comment: Interesting question. I go home, but I never go shops, go school, go work or go pub. And I have no idea why.

Comment: The full OED (behind a paywall, sorry) has a listing for ***home*** as an adverb, defined as [***To** or **towards** one's home, house, or abode; to the place, region, or country where one lives.*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/87872?rskey=XkIlhg&result=4#eid) You won't find any dictionaries listing ***gym*** as an adverb.

Comment: Basically, *home* is special.